# List<Class> to List<string>

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class emp
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class employee
{
    public List<emp> Result { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert above class

```
List<employee> e=new List<employee>();
```

to

```
List<string> onj =new  List<string>();
```

Can anyone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is really unclear!

Comment: Why do you have an `emp` class for your employee? Surely you want to have `Employee` with `Name` and `ID` and then have a `List<Employee>`?

Comment: @ LukeHennerley :my json web service format is like above class....tat's y i hav emp class

Comment: Thanks to all Who spend valuable time to me....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
List<String> onj = e.Select(employee => employee.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: `employee` doesn't have a property `Name` (only `Result`). This won't compile.

Comment: Why is this marked as an answer. This code won't compile because the Employee class don't have a Name property.

Answer (score 2):

Can do something like this

```
public class emp
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

   public override string ToString() {
       return id + " " + name;
   }
}
```

and after

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
List<employee> e=new List<employee>();   
e.ForEach(x=> {
    strings.Add(s.toString());
});
```

So you will get a list of strings where *every* string rapresents `emp` type, like `ID SPACE NAME`

If this is not your intent, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) to join strings, for example with comma:

```
IEnumerable<string> empsNames = e.Select(employee => 
    string.Join(",", employee.Result.Select(emp => emp.name)));
```

If you want to join these via `Enumerable.NewLine`:

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, empsNames);
```

or if you want to create  a `List<String>` from it (as desired ;)):

```
List<string> onj = empsNames.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach (var employee in e) {
{

}
```